# Can I Run 64 Bit Ubuntu OS On Intel® Pentium (R) Processor B940?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, architecture

I have old notebook with Intel® Pentium (R) Processor B940. Can I run the latest 64 bit Ubuntu on my machine? This is detail of my machine taken on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 Bit.

[image: Screenshot of my machine with Ubuntu 32 Bit]

Comment: As Byte Commander stated, your processor is fine. Some cheaper machines (esp. notebooks) have a BIOS (or other hardware) that limits itself to 32bit, but if you can boot the 64bit 'live' install media as Byte suggested - you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Intel's Product Specification site for the B940](https://ark.intel.com/products/55626/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B940-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz#tab-blade-1-0-7) says:

> Instruction set: 64-bit

So it should be possible to install any 64 bit operating system on the machine. Regarding general performance and other resource requirements, just get a live USB of the release you want to try and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with your processor.

You can simple try it using a live CD.